# Encrypt PDF using MuPDF

Tags: pdf, encryption, mupdf

Has anyone done this or can point me to an example?
It is easy to implement document **decryption** using MuPDF: I am trying to do the other way round, but cannot find a suitable entry point.

Answer (score 0):

With the new versions of MuPDF this is now possible as a standard feature.
Implemented in Github repo PyMuPDF (Python bindings for MuPDF) version 1.16.0 and up.